# OpenCover keeps saying "No results, this could be for a number of reasons" for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, opencover

When I run `OpenCover.Console.exe`, it runs tests, but code coverage is failing:
[image: OpenCover Error]

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that build settings `Debugging information` for that project  is set to `Full`(Project->Properties->Build->Advanced).
[image: debugging infromation]

The same can be done by modifying `.csproj` file and adding `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` node under `<PropertyGroup>`.
[image: Change csproj]

Source: [Setting up Coveralls with OpenCover for a .NET Core project](https://blog.markvincze.com/setting-up-coveralls-for-a-net-core-project/)

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was to remove :user from register:user. Just used register and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change to use `-register:administrator` instead. That works for me. see https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/849#issuecomment-454058818.

Answer (score 0):

On VS2022, Framework .NET 4.5, nunit3-console.exe

-register:administrator

worked for me rather than full PDB files

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCover version that worked for be along with `-register` or `-register:administrator` was `4.7.1221`. When I used `4.6.519` it didn't work.

`<DebugType>Full<DebugType>` didn't change anything in my case